# visual studio does not apply css

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to make a small test site using the Metro UI framework (http://metroui.org.ua/)

So, I started up my newly installed Visual Studio 2013 and started a "new website". I added the neccesary css and js and made a very basic masterpage and default.aspx. But here comes the problem: the css does get loaded, but it doesn't get applied. Not in FireFox, not in IE, not in Chrome and not in the "Page Inspector".

It's quite weird, because in my previous VS2012 this same workflow for testing and experimenting with a framework just worked. I really can't find the problem. Maybe it has to do with my new Windows 8.1, my new Visual Basic 2013, maybe an programming error (although that would be very unlikely, since I checked everything).

I also tried installing the framework using NuGet instead of manually adding it. Same result: it does load, but it doesn't get applied.

Anyone knows what's happening here? 
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please add relevant pieces of your code! furthermore I'd have a look at the development tools of major browsers and see if the css is found!

Comment: `maybe an programming error (although that would be very unlikely, since I checked everything)` My favorite line of the day

Comment: I'd love to see some screen shots too, but since you're new here you can't post those yet. If you upload them to imgur and paste the link into your question (edit the original post), then we can inline the image for you.

Comment: I've added a screenshot link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MetroUI](http://metroui.org.ua/) you have to follow 5 simple steps

1. Create page with HTML5 DOCTYPE 
   2.Include metro-bootstrap.css
2. Include    metro.min.js (jquery.js required)
3. **Create main container with class   .metro**
4. Use markup, as described in the pages of this site

In your posted images I can't find a container with class `.metro` . I'd really check the sample code from the posted page.

In case I misunderstood anything please let me know!

Comment: Oh my god. I feel so stupid now (which I am). How could I forget to do that. O.O I've used a lot more frameworks, but I never made such a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: in case you found my answer helpful please consider voting it up and/or marking it as best answer - thx in advance